# Storing various data in a QR code

Tags: qr-code

I want to put a web link, emailto link and some text into a QR code. The emailto field should also contain the subject and some body text. Example QR content (the link and mailto link should be clickable):

```
Some text
www.google.com
mailto:random@gmail.com?subject=SUBJECT_FIELD&body=BODY_TEXT
```

I tried creating a QR code as text. It didn't correctly interpret the mailto link. It does recognize the To: field, but not the subject and body parameter (probably because of the wrong interpretation of the ? and & signs). I know I could overcome this problem by shortening the mailto link with a url shortener, but I would like to avoid that.

I've also tried using the NTT DoCoMo MATMSG format, a multi URL QR code, a VCard, but nothing worked.

Does anybody know if this is even possible and how I could solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a QR code which uses Subject & Body - it seems to work perfectly with ZXing on Android.

[image]

However, QR codes generally only contain *one* piece of information. An email **or** a URL **or** some text.  Trying to put different pieces of content into a QR code will lead to unpredictable behaviour.